# What is the Document Root?

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to implement [this code](http://daleconboy.com/portfolio/code/auto-slideshow) into my page for an automated image rotator, but I'm not sure what exactly needs to go into the 'Directory Root' area in the php code at the top. For now I'm testing locally, and then would be moving it to the server, so does it need to be literally the full path to the file, or just the location within the site itself? This is going on the index page.

Comment: root = at the base area of your server. Just like where a tree starts growing from. ;-)

Comment: root can consist of a few folders, such as `root:cgi-bin` - `root:public_html` etc. `root:/var/user/you/public/`

Comment: If this is the index page, then would I just need to leave it blank?

Comment: Or does it need to look something like "C:\Users\User\web\images\"?

Comment: `root:/public/folder/(assuming index file included)` would leave it blank. I.e.: `/folder/` which would be "folder" starting from root. Accessing `<a href="/folder/">Link to folder under public</a>` tells to look for an index file. No need to do `/folder/index.php` - Edit: *ain't that right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard ;-)

Comment: also, if you haven't a webserver/PHP installed, you won't be able to run that from your own PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is a reserved server variable.

The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

Source :
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php